# missingKeyMapError zk

Tags: google-maps, zk

Google maps do not load in zk. This is my .zul code

```
<?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript" content="zk.googleAPIkey='AIzaSyBwAGLvnAYOtoRd32kkaqOxKuLyMAxcJTs'" />
<window >
    <div>     
        <gmaps id="gmaps" width="520px" height="400px" protocol="https"/>
    </div>
</window>
</zk>
```

Workspace configuration:JAVA 8 AND ZK 8.0.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to ZK Gmaps version 3.0.4 older versions don't transmit the key correctly (mentioned [here](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Diagrams_and_Reports/Gmaps#Mandatory_API_Key)):

[Download](https://github.com/zkoss/zkgmapsz/releases/tag/3.0.4) or Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zkoss.zkforge</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmapsz</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Robert